# How to shift row to left with selected codition in column

Tags: python, dataframe

I am newcomer with Python. there is a dataframe and I would like to change the position of row with value is " " as table below

[image]

the expectation as below:

with column 0 selected row = " " and shift them to left

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve] for your question, including a sample of your data as text, not as a picture, so that we can reproduce it and help you more easily

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy roll function, the code would be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#sample data
m=[['a','b',' '],[' ','c','d'],[' ','e','f']]
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(m)

#to numpy, roll, and back
v1 = dataframe.values
v2 = np.roll(m,-1,1)
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(v2)

#conditional assignment
dataframe.loc[dataframe[0] == ' '] = dataframe2
```